# How to use predict_elm in ELMR

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, package

Package in R : ELMR

```
train<- preProcess(train)
X_train<- train[,1:9]
Y_train<- train[,10:17]

OSelm_training(X_train,Y_train,"classification",150,"hardlim",60,30)

model2 = OSelm_training(X_train,Y_train,"classification",150,"hardlim",60,30)
```

accuracy of model2 = 93.10.

Successfully trained the model and got accuracy

```
test = preProcess(test)

X_test<- data.frame(test[,1:9])
Y_test<- data.frame(test[,10:17])
testing<- data.frame(X_test,Y_test)
```

Obtain the testing data which is to be tested to get validation accuracy

```
accuracy = predict_elm(model2,testing)
```

> Error in matrix(x,ncol(x)) : object 'x' not found

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I will appreciate your help if you help me out with predict_elm()......I couldn't just crack this Error which is like this "Error in matrix(x,ncol(x)) : object 'x' not found "